# How to print this random line?

Tags: javascript, loops

Here is my code

```js
var e=document.getElementById('button');
e.addEventListener('click',function yo(e)
{e.preventDefault();
var a=[
        {'quote':"Result: something good is going to happen with you",},
        {'quote':"Result: your future is very bright i think you are going to meet someone special in your life",},
        {'quote':"Result: just be careful things are not looking good",},
        {'quote':"Result: just be patient in your life if you want everything fine",},
        {'quote':"Result: ohh its difficult please retry ",},
        {'quote':"Result: daymn a good news is coming ",},
        {'quote':"Result: be ready for the upcoming storm my friend",},
        {'quote':"Result:  i dont want to tell you ryt now",},
    
];
var count=0;
var b=document.getElementById('user');
var c=document.createElement('p');
var d=document.getElementById('ha');
var f="";
i=Math.floor(Math.random()*8);//Here alone Math.random*8 gives the number between 0 to 7 and always in float
    //so to make it as whole number we put it inside Math floor
    c=b.value;

var l=a[i].quote;
f="<p>Result: "+ c + +l+  "</p>"
d.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',f);    
})
```

My problem is that when I put user name it does appear in one paragraph but with that instead of showing the quote it shows me `NaN`.

Comment: "when i put user name" ... put where exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It's this line here that is causing the issue:

```
f="<p>Result: "+ c + +l+  "</p>"
```

If we try to break that down as JavaScript sees it we get

- `f =` (assignment)
- `"<p>Result: "` (a string)
- `+` (concatenation)
- `c` (the value in c)
- `+` (concatenation)
- `+l` (unary operation on the value in l)
- `+` (concatenation)
- `"</p>"` (string)

So you are concatenating a bunch of strings, but that extra `+` is taking a string and attempting to convert it to a number. As you can imagine a quote is not a number, thus `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

change this `f="<p>Result: "+ c + +l+  "</p>"`
to `f="<p>Result: "+ c + l+  "</p>"`

You are adding unnecessary **+**